# What are modes in series?

Tags: theory, terminology, modes

I've been reading the explanation to the question about the difference between the term tonal center and guide tone and came across the statement that modes can be in parallel or series. Please explain this statement that modes can be in parallel or series.

Comment: Can you quote and/or cite the relevant passage? Where did you come across the statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a parallel mode?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20196/what-is-a-parallel-mode)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parallel - as in ***Parallel Minor*** - **C-C-C-C-C-C-C** -  lined up with same root, different mode:

- **C** Ionian - **Major**
- **C** Dorian
- **C** Phrygian
- **C** Lydian
- **C** Mixolydian
- **C** Aeolian - ***Parallel* Minor**
- **C** Locrian

Series - in ***serial order*** ->
**C**->
**D**->
**E**->
**F**->
**G**->
**A**->
**B**
over the scale:

- **C** Ionian
- **D** Dorian
- **E** Phrygian
- **F** Lydian
- **G** Mixolydian
- **A** Aeolian
- **B** Locrian

Comment: Succinct, well answered.

Comment: Worth mentioning - *parallel minor in C* also incorporates those notes found in harmonic and melodic minors. Aeolian isn't exclusively the parallel minor. The answer *is* great for the question, though! +1

Comment: So "series" and "parallel" is just terminology without any functional purpose?

Comment: @alephzero - the question appears to be about terminology. That's what I answered. You are certainly free to elaborate on functionality if you deem it necessary.